# quotient of $SL_2\times SL_2$ by matrix group schemes acting by conjugation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $R$ be a ring, and let $G$ be either the $R$-group scheme $PSL_2$ or $PGL_2$. I'm interested in the quotients:

1. of $SL_2\times_R SL_2$ by the simultaneous conjugation action of a $R$-group scheme $G$.
2. of $SL_2\times_R SL_2$ by the simultaneous conjugation action of the **abstract group** $G(R)$.

I'm also interested in their restrictions to subschemes where the action is free.

Do these quotients exist as schemes? What are their properties?

I'd very much appreciate good modern references for this sort of situation. GIT is nice, though it seems to stick to schemes over a field, and I am really interested in the general case.

I'm aware that if the action of $G$ on $X = \text{Spec }A$ is free, then the resulting algebraic space $X/G$ is a scheme as long as one can produce a quasi-finite morphism from $X/G$ to a scheme $Y$. However, while the obvious candidate for $Y$ would be $\text{Spec }A^G$, to check quasi-finiteness one has to find an scheme, etale and surjective over $X/G$, which seems elusive to me when $G$ is infinite.

Of course, when the action isn't free things are even more mysterious.

Comment: one wants to consider the action of $PGL_2$ and not $GL_2$ or $SL_2$, because the action of $SL_2$ is never free.

Comment: @WillSawin Ah of course, good point.

Comment: Also, the quotient by the abstract group certainly doesn't exist as a scheme, because on any affine chart, the functions that are invariant under the abstract group will also be invariant under the group scheme, so the quotient can only exist if the quotient by the group equals the quotient by the group scheme,  which it is not.